# PHP while loops and use of javascript / Jquery associated with different elements inside the loops

Tags: javascript, php, while-loop

As far as I got with my application, I failed to use javascript when I am using PHP while loops. I can`t find a simple answer, or I am stupid enough to don't see the answer.

We all know that while loops returns many results and takes apart each new element by recognising it after his own identification element ( ID from database, for example).

I have the code:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
      {
         echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$row[0]' /></td>"; // here I take individually, each element ID from DB.
         echo "<td><span class='obs_1'>" . $row[4] . " <a href='javascript: show_comment()'>(show obs_2 and hide obs_1)</a></span></td>";
         echo "<td><span class='obs_2' style='display: none;'>" . $row[7] . " <a href='javascript: hide_comment()'>(show obs_1 and hide obs_2)</a></span></td>";
      }
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function show_comment()
     {
         $('.obs_1').hide();
         $('.obs_2').show();
     }

function hide_comment()
     {
         $('.obs_2').hide();
         $('.obs_1').show();
     }
</script>
```

When you click on show_comment, `obs_1` span must disappear and `obs_2` span must be shown for each new element ID. 
The opposite thing for `obs_2`.

I need to assign that ID (`value $row[0]`) to the classes `obs_1` and `obs_2` and I can't manage to do that, in order to show the right `obs_2` and hide `obs_1` for each new element ID.

I have trouble finding answers when it comes to use javascript in PHP while loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you use jQuery, you could use [data-id]. For instance in your case:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
      {
         echo "<td><input type='hidden' value='$row[0]' /></td>"; // here I take individually, each element ID from DB.
         echo "<td><span class='obs_1' data-id='".$row[0]."'>" . $row[4] . " <a href='javascript: show_comment()'>(show obs_2 and hide obs_1)</a></span></td>";
         echo "<td><span class='obs_2' data-id='".$row[0]."' style='display: none;'>" . $row[7] . " <a href='javascript: hide_comment()'>(show obs_1 and hide obs_2)</a></span></td>";
      }
```

So after that in jQuery you can find the right span to hide or show:

```
    jQuery(".obs_1").on('click' ,function(event){
var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
$('.obs_1[data-id="'+id+'"]').hide();
$('.obs_2[data-id="'+id+'"]').show();
});
```

This way anytime you click on a .obs_2 class you will have the right behavior only for the particular data-id elements.

Comment: It works but first click nothing happends. I have to click twice, and then it works both functions.

Comment: Your solution is fine. Just need to eliminate a href or on click because the first click will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that solves your problem, but try to pass the ID as parameter to your JS-functions. Then you can select by these IDs.

Comment: This I am trying to do.

Comment: Add more details which according to you is causing an error

Comment: @BlackMamba Can't manage to get each corresponding ID into javascript.

Answer (score 0):

supposing that every cycle make a new tr, you can use something like this:

```
$('table').on('click','.obs_1', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.obs_2').show();
}).on('click','.obs_2', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.obs_1').show();
});
```

Obviously you can edit the code adding a class or an id to the table, to make the selector more specific :)

In this way you attach only 2 event listener to the table and on click event on obs_1 or obs_2 the script go to the parent tr and search for the other ".obs_" element, hiding himself and show his counterpart

**Edit**

little optimization ;)

```
$('table').on('click','.obs_1, .obs_2', function() {
  var other = $(this).hasClass('obs_1') ? '.obs_2' : '.obs_1';
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).closest('tr').find(other).show();
});
```

**Edit-bis**
with this approach you don't need the `a` tag inside the td

Answer (score -1):

make sure the script tag is located at the right position in code, try to shift it above the loop

Comment: The script is in the footer of the page, where all my scripts are.